# python : HTML table creation from dictionary items

Tags: python, html, dictionary

I am not much aware of HTML. I want to create a HTML table from my dictionary items. Below is my code and output.**I want 'th html tag' key of dictionary  should be on left side and 'td html tag' value of key on right.**

[Output from my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIbdW.png)

```
from testdatabase import DBhelper

db=DBhelper()

item=db.get_user("KASHIF IQBAL")
print(item)

dict1={'ID':item['id'],
'NAME':item['NAME'],
'Project':item['PROJECT_ID'],
'SUBDATE':item['SUBMIT_DATE'],
'ERM Month':item['ERM_MONTH'],
'ERM_SUBMIT':item['ERM_SUBMIT'],
'Claim Period':item['CLAIM_PERIOD'],
'SITE Location':item['LOCATION'],
'Trip Type':item['TRIP_TYPE'],
'Expense Info':item['EXPENSE_INFO'],
'Market claim AmtINR':item['MARKET_CLAIM_INR'],
'Concur Claim AmtINR':item['CONCUR_CLAIM_INR'],
'Market claim AmtEUR':item['MARKET_CLAIM_EUR'],
'Concur claim AmtEUR':item['CONCUR_CLAIM_EUR']
}

f1=open("expense_test.html",'w')
html = """<html><table border="1">"""
for  data in dict1:
   html+="<tr><th>"+data+"</th></tr>".format(data)
   html += r"<tr><td>"+str(dict1[data])+"</td></tr>"
html += "</table></html>"
f1.write(''.join(html))
print(html)
```

Comment: Can you post your actual `dict1` after you find item?

Comment: Your problem isn't the python code, your problem is the html. You can't use `th` like that

Comment: thanks . I have modified like this. 
`for key,value in dict1.items(): html += r"<tr><td>{}</td><td>{}</td></tr>".format(key,value) html += "</table></html>" `

Comment: @KASHIFIQBAL Does it work?

Comment: yes. Even `for key,value in dict1.items(): html += r"<tr><th>{}</th><td>{}</td></tr>".format(key,value) html += "</table></html>"`
gave me output what i want.

Answer (score 0):

change your for loop to:

```
for data in dict1:
   html += "<tr>"
   html += "<td>"+data+"</td>"
   html += "<td>"+str(dict1[data])+"</td>"
   html += "</tr>"
```

Comment: thanks . I have modified like this . 
for  key,value in dict1.items():
   html += r"<tr><td>{}</td><td>{}</td></tr>".format(key,value)
html += "</table></html>"